# How to generate radio button with label tag completely outside input tag in yii2

Tags: html, yii2, radio-button

Yii2 `HTML::radio()` helper generate html input tag with label tag around that input like this:

```
<label>
   <input type="radio" name="abc" value="1"> Hello
</label>
```

But I need it like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="abc" value="1" id="radio1">
<label for "radio1">Hello</label>
```

Is it postible to custozime this inside [radio helper](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#radio-detail) ?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. As you can see from `yii\helper\BaseHtml` class code, this nesting of tags comes from the source code of `radio()` method, without means of configuration by changing options.

What you need is override that method. It's really easy.

1. In the namespace `app\helpers`, create class `Html`. Put it into a new file named `/Helpers/Html.php` relative to your app root (if you've got Yii basic app), and put something like this inside:

```
    namespace app\helpers;

    use Yii;
    use yii\helpers\BaseHtml;

    class Html extends BaseHtml
    {
        public static function radio($name, $checked = false, $options = [])
        {
            $options['checked'] = (bool) $checked;
            $value = array_key_exists('value', $options) ? $options['value'] : '1';
            if (isset($options['uncheck'])) {
                // add a hidden field so that if the radio button is not selected, it still submits a value
                $hidden = static::hiddenInput($name, $options['uncheck']);
                unset($options['uncheck']);
            } else {
                $hidden = '';
            }
            if (isset($options['label'])) {
                $label = $options['label'];
                $labelOptions = isset($options['labelOptions']) ? $options['labelOptions'] : [];
                unset($options['label'], $options['labelOptions']);
                $content = static::input('radio', $name, $value, $options);
                $content .= static::label($label, null, $labelOptions);
                return $hidden . $content;
            } else {
                return $hidden . static::input('radio', $name, $value, $options);
            }
        }
    }
```

Explanation:

> We've just copied the code of `radio()` method from `yii\helpers\BaseHtml` and changed the lines containing `static::label()` to separate output of `static::input()` from it;
>  
>  Since both original and our custom classes extend `yii\helpers\BaseHtml`, and original `yii\helpers\Html` is not redefining none of BaseHtml methods, there will be no loss in logic for elements other than radio. 
>  
>  Namespace and class name shouldn't be exactly the same, but obviously they should just differ from `yii\helpers\Html`.

2. Just replace `use yii\helpers\Html;` with `use app\helpers\Html;` in your View code.

That's all!